# How do I enable gnome 40's Horizontal Workspaces on Manjaro Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, manjaro

I recently switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro linux. It comes with Gnome 40.1.0, but workspaces are still horizontal rather than vertical. My assumption is that Manjaro set vertical workspaces to be the default, even in Gnome 40, but I don't know *how* they did this, or how to enable horizontal workspaces (now that they have native support in Gnome 40).

Most of the solutions I found online described extensions for horizontal workspaces in Gnome 3, but these should either be rendered unnecessary or entirely obsolete by Gnome 40.

My questions are:

- How did Manjaro make Gnome 40's workspaces vertical?
- How do I make them vertical again?

[image: Picture of desktop environment workspace overview]

## Gnome Extensions:

One person suggested that it might be a vertical-overview extension. Using `gnome-extensions list` I checked for a vertical-overview extension, but I couldn't find one.

This is the list of installed extensions:

```
appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
arcmenu@arcmenu.com
auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
ding@rastersoft.com
drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
gamemode@christian.kellner.me
gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
material-shell@papyelgringo
native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
nightthemeswitcher@romainvigier.fr
pamac-updates@manjaro.org
places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
unite@hardpixel.eu
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

Comment: That looks extremely like GNOME Shell 3.38 – they reverted _all_ UI changes, not just workspaces.

Comment: I just checked, and... you're right. Even though settings lists the gnome version as 40.1.0, it's running gnome shell 3.38.4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Gnome, but looking up "vertical workspaces gnome 40" gives you this project.

https://github.com/RensAlthuis/vertical-overview

I would assume you install this extension. Manjaro probably just comes pre-bundled with it.

You could probably disable the extension to make it horizontal.

Comment: I checked but it wasn't installed! I included the full list of extensions in my post

Answer (score 0):

## Solution: Enable horizontal-workspaces extension

For some reason, despite coming with gnome-40, workspaces are vertical by default in Manjaro, but the OS comes packaged with a horizontal-workspaces extension that's turned off by default. If that extension is switched on, horizontal workspaces are enabled. You can get to this window by searching for the "Extensions" app, or by running:

```bsh
gnome-extensions enable horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

[image]